# Access sys.argv as bytes in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

As the title said, is there a `sys.argv` equivalent in python 3 allow me to read arguments as bytes?

The reason I want this is, I have a script which accept a bytes (\xe9\x88...) as its first arg, the first arg is supposed to be a bytes converted from an utf8 string, sys.argv will try to decode the first arg using some encoding, which may not utf8, so the program may fail. If I can access the args without calling sys.argv, the conversion will not be done.

Comment: What's the OS and system locale settings? How is a "string in another encoding" passed in the arguments? This determines what the program actually gets from the system.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There was an [issue on the Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue8776) about this:

> In some situations, the encoding of the command line is incorrect or
>   unknown. sys.argv is decoded with the file system encoding which can
>   be wrong. Eg. see issue #4388 (ok, it's a bug, it should be fixed).
>
> As os.environb, it would be useful to have bytes version of sys.argv
>   to have able to decide the encoding used to decode each argument, or
>   to manipulate bytes if we don't care about the encoding.

Since on Python 3 `sys.argv` is encoded with the filesystem encoding, the proposed solution on the bug is to use [`os.fsencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsencode):

```
argvb = list(map(os.fsencode, sys.argv))
```

`os.fsencode` encodes the string using the string using the `surrogateescape` encoding, which is defined in [PEP-383](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383).